# What options are there to deploy a VueJS dist folder

Tags: node.js, git, express, deployment, vuejs2

I am writing a number of VueJS apps that take part in a larger Microservices environment. My current workflow seems long winded but I can't find anything better and would like advice on how I could do it better. Here is my current work flow.

1. Write VueJS development version (testapp)
2. Push testapp to git server
3. npm rum build to get a dist folder
4. Create a nodejs/express app (testapp_server)
5. Copy testapp dist folder to the testapp_server html folder
6. Push testapp_server to git server
7. On production server clone testapp_server from git
8. pm2 start app.js --name testapp_server

If I make changes to my VueJS test app in dev, I have to go through this whole process again to get it into production.

I am on a closed secure network, so I don't have the luxury of using Heroku etc.

Is there a better way?

**Update:** I have just found out about git sparse-checkout which allows the checking out of specific folders from a repo. I am thinking I could include my dist folder in my development git repo and then just check out the dist folder using sparse-checkout directly into a node/express app on my production server.

Comment: I'm guessing you're working in enterprise environment since you're behind a closed network, but do you at least have access to an internal CI/CD tool such as Jenkins? I can't see any way to really automate this without it.

Comment: @FranciscoMateo Thank you. I have thought about that, but I am not keen on adding another tool, at least not at yet, but in the future I may deploy ansible. I am going to have a look at using GIT's sparse-checkout option tomorrow and see how far that gets me.